# How would I cycle through an open Outlook windows using VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

I often have multiple email items open, some that I composed that are not yet sent and others that I received that I didn't yet close but I am referencing.

What I would like to do is have a fast way to cycle through all of the open windows to find the one that I am looking for.

In Excel I created a macro to cycle through the tabs of an Excel document like this.

```
Sub PreviousSheet()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
End Sub

Sub NextSheet()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Next.Select 
End Sub
```

In Outlook, how would I cycle through the open windows using VBA?

**Update**

```
Sub test()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = GetOutlookApp()

    'I think this is how to loop through the open items?
    For i = olApp.Inspectors.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set olItem = olApp.Inspectors.Item(i).CurrentItem
        olItem.Select 'How do I set focus?
    Next i

End Sub

Function GetOutlookApp() As Outlook.Application
     ' returns reference to native Application object
    Set GetOutlookApp = Outlook.Application
End Function
```

Comment: `Application.Windows`?

Comment: I don't see that propetry

Comment: You want `olApp.Insectors(i).Activeate` to set the focus. You don't need a reference to the Item. Incidentally, I use Alt+tab for this. Also, I'm interested how you're going to call this macro.

Comment: In a counter-intuitive way, at least for me, when you get the inspector(i) and points it to CurrentItem, you can access all the properties, even though it is not a "real" current selected item: `outlook.Application.Inspectors.item(1).CurrentItem.FullName`  

Speaking of counter-intuitive way, Inspectors collection is not 0-based...

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub GetPreviousOpenItem()

    Set MainWindow = Application.ActiveExplorer

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = GetOutlookApp()

    If olApp.ActiveInspector Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ActiveInspectorIndex = GetIndexOfActiveInspector(olApp, olApp.ActiveInspector)

    If ActiveInspectorIndex - 1 > 0 Then
        Dim PreviousInspector As Inspector
        Set PreviousInspector = olApp.Inspectors(ActiveInspectorIndex - 1)
        olApp.Inspectors(ActiveInspectorIndex - 1).Display
    Else
        olApp.Inspectors(olApp.Inspectors.Count).Display
    End If

    MainWindow.Activate

End Sub

Sub GetNextOpenItem()

    Set MainWindow = Application.ActiveExplorer

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = GetOutlookApp()

    If olApp.ActiveInspector Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ActiveInspectorIndex = GetIndexOfActiveInspector(olApp, olApp.ActiveInspector)

    If ActiveInspectorIndex + 1 <= olApp.Inspectors.Count Then
        Dim NextInspector As Inspector
        Set NextInspector = olApp.Inspectors(ActiveInspectorIndex + 1)
        NextInspector.Display
    Else
        olApp.Inspectors(1).Display
    End If

    MainWindow.Activate

End Sub

Function GetIndexOfActiveInspector(olApp, CurrentItem) As Integer

    CurrentItem = olApp.ActiveInspector

    For i = 1 To olApp.Inspectors.Count

        Dim Inspector
        Set Inspector = olApp.Inspectors.Item(i)
        Set olItem = Inspector.CurrentItem

        If olItem Is CurrentItem Then
            GetIndexOfActiveInspector = i
            Exit Function
        End If

    Next i

    MainWindow.Activate

End Function
Function GetOutlookApp() As Outlook.Application
     ' returns reference to native Application object
    Set GetOutlookApp = Outlook.Application
End Function
```